# how to fix : shows StartDate and EndDate in slowly changing dimension

Tags: ssis

system not shows column Start Date and End Date

[image]

I am try changing package and dimension but not pass . it is not show Start Date and End Date , I don't know do it. I am try any way to fix it but doesn't work either

Comment: Can you post the table definition? Specifically, I'd like to know what that data types are for your Start/End Date columns. In SSMS, right click on table and click Script to new window. Click Edit on your question and paste the definition.

Comment: data type is date . if data type is string it is the same